# Rotate <text> not working in ie11 IE11 on Windows 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-11

I draw svg use d3 js use transform:rotate(180deg). It's perfect show on chrome but when ie11 it not woking. I'm change to rotateY(180deg) it woking with div element but still not working with text element.  This is my screen and code :

IE/Chorme: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXaUC.jpg

```
<g class="node" transform="translate(1356, 161.11111450195312)"><circle class="node" r="25" style="fill: rgb(12, 230, 103);" cursor="pointer"></circle><text x="-246" y="0" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start" class="area-name">Area 4</text><text x="-70" y="50" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start" >30 Jan 2019 10:33 PM</text><text x="-70" y="70" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start" cursor="pointer" class="text-decorate">Abc</text>
```

My Css:

```
text{
    webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);           
    -sand-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: You'd need to modify the transform attribute on IE11. CSS transforms don't work there as you've discovered yourself.

Comment: How to modify the transform attribute on IE11? I think it's working with div element and not working with text element

Comment: element.setAttribute("transform", "some new value") perhaps

Answer (score 1):

I tried removing your CSS and it worked for me for both Chrome and IE.

If that's not what you want then share your code so we can understand what exactly you want.

Happy Coding ☻